# Remove line breaks _x000D_\n (Remove)

Tags: line, removeall

I am concatenate several files (50 or more) but it has the *x000D*\n at the end of the line, I have tried rstrip and other options to remove it, but not able.  The problem is that when I export it to a csv file programs like Tableau can not read it.  Excel yes, but I am working with dashboards.

The rows appear like this:
NACIONAL_x000D_\n
NACIONAL_x000D_\n
NACIONAL_x000D_\n....

I can go and remove that in the Excel files but it is painful a time killer.  Any advice thank you.